Prisma, delete row if child count is less than 1
so I am working on a mini roguelike game using Prisma for database management. What I am trying to do is some cleanup on inventory items.
There is an Inventory table that relates to Many Items.
What I would like to do is something to the effect of:


prisma.Inventory.deletMany({
  where: {
    Items: {
      count: {
        lt: 1
      }
    }
  }
})



I am using SQLite for the database but I could also use other DBs later (possibly thinking of multiplayer options down the road).
Is there a way to do this with Prisma that doesn't manually get the count, mapping over each, and then extract the ids? I have been looking through the docs but not sure if I missed something as this seems like it should be a feature already.
I would also prefer not to do the SQL execution just for laziness purposes
